# How can I avoid conflicts between plugin and theme?

Tags: plugin-development, css, javascript

I'm developing a widget for wp elementor as a plugin. Now my widget front view css and the theme front view css are in conflict. Right now as a developer how can I avoid wp plugin front view css and theme front view css conflict?

Comment: There’s no magic trick. You just need to write your CSS rules with appropriate specificity so that rules you want to be overwritten can be while important CSS is not overwritten.

Answer (score 5):

You can/should prefix all your classes. That way you have very limited chance to have conflicting classes, which can cause unexpected behaviour on the front-end. So, instead of `.container`, you can use `.mypluginprefix_container`.